# Vertex AI - Deployment failed

Tags: docker, flask, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to deploy my custom-trained model using a custom-container, i.e. create an endpoint from a model that I created.
I'm doing the same thing with AI Platform (same model & container) and it works fine there.

At the first try I deployed the model successfully, but ever since whenever I try to create an endpoint it says "deploying" for 1+ hours and then it fails with the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 Error: model server never became ready. Please validate that your model file or container configuration are valid. Model server logs can be found at (link)
```

The log shows the following:

```
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080
[05/Jul/2022 12:00:37] "[33mGET /v1/endpoints/1/deployedModels/2025850174177280000 HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[05/Jul/2022 12:00:38] "[33mGET /v1/endpoints/1/deployedModels/2025850174177280000 HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
```

Where the last line is being spammed until it ultimately fails.

My flask app is as follows:

```
import base64
import os.path
import pickle
from typing import Dict, Any
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from streamliner.models.general_model import GeneralModel

class Predictor:
    def __init__(self, model: GeneralModel):
        self._model = model

    def predict(self, instance: str) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        decoded_pickle = base64.b64decode(instance)
        features_df = pickle.loads(decoded_pickle)
        prediction = self._model.predict(features_df).tolist()
        return {"prediction": prediction}

app = Flask(__name__)
with open('./model.pkl', 'rb') as model_file:
    model = pickle.load(model_file)
    predictor = Predictor(model=model)


@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict() -> Any:
    if request.method == "POST":
        instance = request.get_json()
        instance = instance['instances'][0]
        predictions = predictor.predict(instance)
        return jsonify(predictions)


@app.route("/health")
def health() -> str:
    return "ok"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

The deployment code which I do through Python is irrelevant because the problem persists when I deploy through GCP's UI.

The model creation code is as follows:

```
def upload_model(self):
    model = {
        "name": self.model_name_on_platform,
        "display_name": self.model_name_on_platform,
        "version_aliases": ["default", self.run_id],
        "container_spec": {
            "image_uri": f'{REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/{GCP_PROJECT_ID}/{self.repository_name}/{self.run_id}',
            "predict_route": "/predict",
            "health_route": "/health",
        },
    }
    parent = self.model_service_client.common_location_path(project=GCP_PROJECT_ID, location=REGION)
    model_path = self.model_service_client.model_path(project=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
                                                      location=REGION,
                                                      model=self.model_name_on_platform)
    upload_model_request_specifications = {'parent': parent, 'model': model,
                                           'model_id': self.model_name_on_platform}
    try:
        print("trying to get model")
        self.get_model(model_path=model_path)
    except NotFound:
        print("didn't find model, creating a new one")
    else:
        print("found an existing model, creating a new version under it")
        upload_model_request_specifications['parent_model'] = model_path
    upload_model_request = model_service.UploadModelRequest(upload_model_request_specifications)
    response = self.model_service_client.upload_model(request=upload_model_request, timeout=1800)
    print("Long running operation:", response.operation.name)
    upload_model_response = response.result(timeout=1800)
    print("upload_model_response:", upload_model_response)
```

My problem is very close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69316032/custom-container-deployment-in-vertex-ai) with the difference that I do have a health check.

Why would it work on the first deployment and fail ever since? Why would it work on AI Platform but fail on Vertex AI?

Comment: Have you found the cause/solution?

Comment: @mon Not yet, still working on it

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be due to different reasons:

1. Validate the container configuration port, it should use port 8080.
   This configuration is important because Vertex AI sends liveness
   checks, health checks, and prediction requests to this port on the
   container. You can see this document about [containers](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements#aip-variables), and this
   other about [custom containers](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/use-custom-container).
2. Another possible reason is [quota limits](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/quotas), which could need to be increased. You will be able to verify this using [this document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota) to do it
3. In the health and predict route use the MODEL_NAME  you are using.
   Like this example

```
"predict_route": "/v1/models/MODEL_NAME:predict",
 "health_route": "/v1/models/MODEL_NAME",
```

4. Validate that the account you are using has enough permissions to
   read your project's GCS bucket.
5. Validate the Model location, should be the correct path.

If any of the suggestions above work, it’s a requirement to contact GCP Support by creating a [Support Case](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) to fix it. It’s impossible for the community to troubleshoot it without using internal GCP resources

Comment: @Roee Additionally to what Raul states (which is accurate), sometimes GCP engineers need to properly analyze your custom-trained model to find the root cause, the only way to achieve it is with a Support Case.

Comment: About 1, as you can see in the container's code that I provided, I run my app on 8080. The only related attribute that I found outside of the container was in Vertex's Model.upload() method and  was called serving_container_ports, but the docs says it's not important: Declaration of ports that are exposed by the container. This field is primarily informational, it gives Vertex AI information about the network connections the container uses. Listing or not a port here has no impact on whether the port is actually exposed, any port listening on the default "0.0.0.0" will be accessible

Comment: About 2, as I understand these quotas only apply to concurrent models. I deleted the model that I previously managed to get to work, so right now I have 0 working models and it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't yet found a solution you can try out custom prediction routines. They are really helpful as they strip away the necessity to write the server part of the code and allows us to focus solely on the logic of our ml model and any kind of pre or post processing. Here is the link to help you out https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-cpr-sklearn#0. Hope this helps.